# Height not working?

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to create a contents part of a web page with some pictures and writing. When I remove some writing it adjusts but when I then drag the screen to a bigger screen the layout goes all wrong. I don't know why this happens. Also is there not a way where the pictures can adapt to how much writing I have. So when I delete some writing the pictures will still fit on the page and keep the correct layout instead of me having to delete some pictures for it to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/uvdtrx39/1/

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <div id="header-content">
            <div class="hire"><h3>For Hire</h3></div>
            <h1><a href="index.html" >Black Cab Tours</a></h1>

                    <nav class="cl-effect-8">
                    <ul>
                <li><a href="tours.html">Tours</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Review</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="banner">
        <h2>Who knows London better than a black cab driver.</h2>
    </div>


    <div id="content">

          <div class="pics">
        <ul class="gallery">

            <li><a class="pic-2"><img src="img/Big-Ben.jpg" alt="Photograph of clouds and sunlight" /></a></li>
            <li><a class="pic-3"><img src="img/guards.jpg" alt="Photograph of clouds and sunlight" /></a></li>
                        <li><a class="pic-4"><img src="img/londoneye.jpg" alt="Photograph of clouds and sunlight" /></a></li>

            <li><a class="pic-5"><img src="img/Borough_Market.jpg" alt="Photograph of clouds and sunlight" /></a></li>




    </ul>

    </div>  
        <article>
            <p>London Tours by Taxi offers one of the most informative, unique and unforgettable ways of experiencing the diverse and historic city of London. Being driven in one of the world’s most famous London black cabs, with a driver who has an intimate knowledge of the city. As well as being a licensed black taxi driver with over 24 years of experience, I have undertaken additional training and am also a qualified City of London Guide and Black Taxi Guide. My taxi is the very latest Mercedes Vito black cab, fully air conditioned, has wheelchair access and can take six passengers in comfort. Tours are priced per cab, not per person. Click here for more reasons why a tour in a London Black Taxi is a good idea. Read what other people have said about my tours – Click here‘ I am more than happy to tailor tours to suit you and your party and am very flexible on sights you wish to see. After all, it is your tour! I can pick you up from your central London hotel/accommodation or, other central London location and drop you back there (included in tour price). If you have a layover stop in London, you can take the express train into London and I am happy to meet you from a train station to start your tour. I will of course take you back to your station after the tour if you wish. By taking the train, this will be much more time/cost effective for you. Please see the make a booking page for postcodes in Central London. Other areas outside of these may incur an additional cost for pick up/drop off.
</p>


        </article>

        <div class="footer">
            <hr>
            <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Images don't appear in your JSFiddle; you might be able to approximate to demonstrate the issues by embedding URLs from this site that match your own image's sizes: http://dummyimage.com

Comment: if you look a the jsfiddle again I have changed the background color. You can see the red when you scroll to the bottom which isn't meant to happen. I want the content to fill the rest of the page.

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uvdtrx39/2/?

Comment: In your fiddle, you shouldn't use `//` for comments. `//` is not css. Use `/*` .. `*/` instead. Also, can you explain better what the problem is?